# Using 'if' condition in parameters

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I am creating *JasperReports Server* report using *iReport*. I have a table with 4 columns. The user needs to select through parameter which will be the first column. Depending on what he selects, the other columns be decided.

For e.g. If user selects column 2 in the input control, the column 2 will become the leftmost column and column 1 will take the place of column 2.

What is the best way to do it? Can I use 'if' condition in parameters?

Comment: Can you post your jrxml file with one condition?

Answer (score 1):

The arrangement of solutions is quite rare. Anyways, you can achieve so by using an expression with a variable.

Simply right-click on the field and click "Edit Expression"

```
PFirst is a reports parameter
```

The field expression can be something like

`$Pfirst.equals("fieldOne")?fieldOne:"" + $Pfirst.equals("fieldTwo")?fieldTwo:"" + $Pfirst.equals("fieldThree")?fieldThree:""`

Answer (score 0):

Add another parameter (uncheck use as a prompt) with your if statement in default value expression.
The whole sql statement can be in this parameter, I assume, but tested with only part of sql statement. In the report query put this new parameters as $P!{paramname}.
Should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

If condition for text filed of first column, p_column is a parameter with default value "col1"

```
 $P{p_column}.equals("col1") ? $F{col1} : $F{col2}
```

If condition for the second text filed of second column:-

```
$P{p_column}.equals( "col1" ) ? $F{col2} : $F{col1}
```